# Efficient grouping of parallel arrays/vectors in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, root, bigdata, grid-computing

I have a very large dataset in ROOT (binary) format containing serialized std::vector objects. Each vector of length N essentially represents a data member of a collection of N logical objects (here, N may vary with each entry in the file). For example, for every entry in the file, I read the following objects:

```
std::vector<float> foo_a;
std::vector<float> foo_b;
std::vector<int> foo_c;
```

Logically, these parallel fields represent an object. I want to be able to process the data as though I had this instead:

```
struct Foo {
    float a;
    float b;
    int c;
};
std::vector<Foo> my_foos;
```

So that, e.g. if I want to remove a certain "Foo" from the list, or transform it in place, etc., I don't want to have to track down all of its parallel data members to make the change.

I access the serialized objects via Python, using a library that simply hands off the pythonized std::vector objects for each entry I request. Technically, the same vectors persist in memory throughout the file access; they're cleared and refilled with new data from each entry. Here's a sketch of how I'm currently object-ifying:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self): pass

def get_objects(list_of_field_names, list_of_parallel_vectors):

    names_and_vectors = zip(list_of_field_names, list_of_parallel_vectors)

    n = len(list_of_parallel_vectors[0])
    for i in xrange(n):
        obj = Dummy()
        obj_members = [(field_name, vector.at(i))
            for field_name, vector in names_and_vectors]

        obj.__dict__.update(obj_members)

        yield obj

# ...

# get the std::vectors from file:
foo_a, foo_b, foo_c = magic()

# retrieve my python list of Foo objects:
objects_to_process = get_objects( ('a','b','c'), (foo_a, foo_b, foo_c) )

# now I can access logical data in the parallel vectors as a python object:
for obj in objects_to_process:
    print (obj.a + obj.b) / obj.c
```

After profiling, I find that all the overhead of object creation and data copying from the vectors to the python objects are significant bottleneck in processing time. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same effect?

Principled and sagely advice regarding the perils of optimization or wiser ways to skin this cat are welcome, but keep in mind that: 1) The datasets are huge (up to 100's of TB); there are millions of entries and thousands of parallel vectors of various length (corresponding to dozens of logical objects). 2) I don't have any control over the input data format.